# Difference between DbNull.Value and DbNull.Value.ToString()

Tags: c#, dbnull, sqlparameter

I wanted to learn which usage is true?

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentID))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParentSesID", parentID));
else
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParentSesID", DBNull.Value));
```

OR

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentID))
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParentSesID", parentID));
else
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParentSesID", DBNull.Value.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParentSesID", parentID));
```

This is passing a parentID to parameter @ParentSesID.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParentSesID", DBNull.Value));
```

is passing a `null` value to parameter.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParentSesID", DBNull.Value.ToString()));
```

is passing equal to `string.Empty`, which is not allowed in numerical data types.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParentSesID", null);
```

is same as ignoring the parameter.

So when you need to pass `null` to SP you've to pass `DBNull.Value`.

Comment: so DBNull.Value and null is not same?

Comment: @Sudhakar Nope, when you say `null` you're ignoring the parameter and `DBNull` says you're passing a null value to DB

Comment: so we can not pass null when table column is defined as not null right?

Comment: @Sudhakar When table is defined as `not null` you can't pass either `null` or `DbNull` both will fail

Comment: Okay, then when we will be using `null` instead of `DBNull.Value`? i think we should never use `null` then right?

Comment: @Sudhakar That is database specific.

Comment: @Sudhakar `null` is certainly not required. I added it in my answer to avoid confusion and the diff b/w DBNull and null.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Thanks for your explanation , your answer is very clear now.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Does sending a DbNull.Value.ToString() as parameter is shown in db column NULL or "" ?

Comment: @cihata87 It it equal to passing empty string ""

Answer (score 2):

This one: `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParentSesID", DBNull.Value));` is a correct, in case the field you are writing to can accept `NULL` value in database.

This one:  `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParentSesID", DBNull.Value.ToString()));` if the field is a, say, `VARCHAR`, and does not accept `NULL`, but you want to indicate in some way an absence of value in that field, so you write inside *your application specific* "no value" value. So your application knows, if it founds that value in the field, that means: no value.

Answer (score 1):

[`DBNull.Value.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkbzs85t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will return empty string, so I think

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParentSesID", DBNull.Value));
```

is a good approach and here the only approach

see here:

http://ideone.com/iGo1Jh